Unsupported hypervisor
When I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 on virtual machine, an error message appeared (see attached photo). But I could bypass the message and installed Ubuntu 24.04 on virtual machine on my windows 10 laptop which is Dell Inspiron. Thee problem here is Ubuntu window is taller than physical window, hence have to move the window up and down.
I have installed Kali linux on the virtual machine without any issue.

Did you install "VirtualBox Guest Additions" to the Ubuntu system?
